# How to access/save istio logs in windows 10?

Tags: metrics, istio

I installed istio version 1.7.3 on windows 10 using Docker Desktop 3.2.2 and successfully run the sample bookinfo demo. I started prometheus to see http logs when sending requests to localhost/productpage. I want to be able to save those logs in my host machine (windows 10). Additionally I want to save istio metrics and logs components (mixer, citadel, envoy, etc.) to windows too, how can I achieve such a thing? and the path `/dev/null` specified in [here](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging) it concerns the path for the pod itself?

**EDIT:**

the following [documentation](https://istio.io/v1.1/docs/tasks/telemetry/logs/fluentd/) in istio v 1.1 uses fluentd, elasticsearch and kibana to collect logs, how can I apply this to istio v 1.7 ?

Comment: didnt understood path part. you said it concerns to `/dev/null`, but there is a `/dev/stdout` in the example you provided.

Comment: yes they changed it to `/dev/stdout` so how can I export those logs to my host or db? and how can I see istio service logs?

Answer (score 0):

The [Logging with Mixer and Fluentd](https://istio.io/v1.7/docs/tasks/observability/mixer/logs/fluentd/) sais that Istio 1.7 is the last one that support [Mixer](https://istio-releases.github.io/v0.1/docs/concepts/policy-and-control/mixer.html).

> Mixer is deprecated. The functionality provided by Mixer is being
> moved into the Envoy proxies. Use of Mixer with Istio will only be
> supported through the 1.7 release of Istio.

So basically, if your Istio < 1.8, you still can use [Istio Logging with Mixer and Fluentd](https://istio.io/v1.7/docs/tasks/observability/mixer/logs/fluentd/) and configure logs through Fluentd / Elasticsearch / Kibana stack.

Starting from version 1.8 [Mixer is no longer supported in Istio](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/1.8.x/announcing-1.8/upgrade-notes/#mixer-is-no-longer-supported-in-istio)